# Indexing multiple elements in a muldimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I would like to extract elements of a given multidimensional numpy array, using another array of indices. However it doesn't behave in the way I expected. Below is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((3, 3, 3))
idx = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]])

b = a[idx]
print(b.shape)  # expect (2, ), got (2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Why is that the case? And how should I modify the code so that `b` contains only two elements: `a[0, 0, 0]` and `a[0, 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for numpy advanced indexing

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

In your case, you need to use `idx` on each axis:

```py
a[idx[:,0], idx[:, 1], idx[:, 2]].shape == (2,)  # True
```

Comment: Thank you! On a side note, what if the number of columns of `idx` is not known in advance? (For example, it could be a function argument). I tried `a[*idx.T]` but it shows `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @JingyangWang Just `a[tuple(idx.T)]`.